# How to get these two divs on the same height?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, alignment

I am making a minimalistic menu with a portfolio logo (that dribbble logo is just a placeholder) and a right-aligned select box for sorting the posts by some tags. Of course both divs should be on the same line – but somehow the select box is not aligned with the logo. What am I doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<!-- MENU ------------------------>
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#">
    <img id="portfolioLogo" src="http://cdn.embed.ly/providers/logos/dribbble.png" />
  </a>

  <div id="sort">
    <div class="sortMenu">Sortieren nach
        <div class="menuLine"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="showMenu">
        <div class="menuLink">Corporate Design</div>
        <div class="menuLink">Logo</div>
        <div class="menuLink">Symbol</div>
        <div class="menuLink">Web</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#menu {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  vertical-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  top: 0;
}

#portfolioLogo {
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: red;
}

#sort {
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size:;
  float: right;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px;
}

.sortMenu {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing:0.1em;
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 15pt;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color:;
}

.menuLine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2.5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.showMenu {
  display: none;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  filter: alpha(opacity=70); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}

.menuLink {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.menuLink a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-style: normal;
  color: black;
}

.menuLink a:hover {
  border-bottom:1px dotted;
}
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function showHide() {
  $('.sortMenu').click(function showHide() {
    $('.showMenu').slideToggle("fast");
  });
});
```

Here is the fiddle with the problem code: http://jsfiddle.net/7f9aX/

Comment: Use display:inline-block; for #portfolioLogo .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving `display:block` to a tag i.e. `#portfolioLogo` so that it work as a div so it inherits its parents width so it treated as full width div that's why a sortMenu div is not aligned with the logo.

You can make two div with float left property and proper width to align them or use a `inline-block` property.

Comment: the problem is that `#portfolioLogo` isn't centered anymore…

Comment: You have to just check for heights and padding for both divs.

Answer (score 1):

I use `display:inline-block` as so:

```
#menu {
    white-space:nowrap; /* prevent items from bumping down */
}
#menu > * {
    display:inline-block;  /* display items as box; wrap items as text */
    vertical-align:bottom; /* vertically align objects (feel free to change) */
    white-space:normal;    /* restore whitespace normally */
    float:none;            /* no need to float */
}
```

If you paste that into the bottom of your fiddle, it should work.

Comment: and how can I get `#portfolioLogo` centered?